# Configuration Errors upgrading from Azure 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: azure

I am trying to migrate to Visual Studio 2012 and Azure 1.7 from 2010 and 1.6.  When I upgraded my worker project, I am now getting a bunch of errors like:

> CloudServices58 : Cannot load imported module named 'Antimalware.'

Which brings me to this in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets:

```
  <Target Name="PreValidateServiceModel">
    <ValidateServiceFiles
        AllowLegacyWebRoles="$(AllowLegacyWebRoles)"
        ServiceDefinitionFile="@(SourceServiceDefinition)"
        ServiceConfigurationFile="@(SourceServiceConfiguration)">
    </ValidateServiceFiles>
  </Target>
```

And errors like this in my cscfg file:

> The setting
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ServiceLocation' for role
>   MyProject.ProcessLogs is specified in the service configuration file,
>   but it is not declared in the service definition file.

The error brings me to here:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <...stuff.../>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ServiceLocation" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.EnableAntimalware" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.EnableRealtimeProtection" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.EnableWeeklyScheduledScans" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.DayForWeeklyScheduledScans" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.TimeForWeeklyScheduledScans" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ExcludedExtensions" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ExcludedPaths" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ExcludedProcesses" value="" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

I am pretty lost, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to download and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29209

Comment: Just what I was looking for!