# Upgrading Windows Azure project to 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have Windows Azure project base on a fairly old 1.8 (October 2012) SDK. I need to upgrade it to 2.2 SDK to be able to use it in Visual Studio 2013.

When I do the upgrade, the project does not compile and I get

```
CloudServices58 : Cannot load imported module named 'Connect.'  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.2\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets
```

I found a smillar error message in [Configuration Errors upgrading from Azure 1.6 to 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960361/configuration-errors-upgrading-from-azure-1-6-to-1-7) but the answer is not relevant for me.

Any idea what the error means and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using Windows Azure Connect in this project?

Comment: There is a Import section with Connect in the definition file, is this Windows Azure Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure Connect is deprecated.  You can either stay on the older SDK version, or upgrade Connect to Point-to-site VPN: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/